# How to pass an array in to an array to PHP a server?

Tags: php, jquery, html, symfony

I have the next multiple field in my html view:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="search[cpuUsage[]]"
    id="search_cpu_usage"
    class="form-control">
    {% for statu in status %}
        <option value="{{ statu }}">{{ statu }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

i need all possible values that user select, and i try save in `search[cpuUsage[]]`, but this not work because `php` only get the last selected value. if i use only `cpuUsage[]` without `search[]` works perfectly.

For send to server i use `jquery.serialice`.

any idea of how do for work `search[cpuUsage[]]`

Comment: `cpuUsage[]` is an array already why do you need the `search` array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have `name` attribute as an array

So change

```
name="search[cpuUsage[]]"
```

To:-

```
name="search[cpuUsage][]" //or name="search[]" or name="cpuUsage[]"
```

And you are good to go